# Local Database: Not loading all the changes of the tables and views

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using `Visual Studio 2012` and an `SQL Server` Database.
At first, my program loads all the tables as well as views but when I try to do some modifications to the database schema (e.g. add some views) the changes are not reflected when I deleted the connection in the Solution Explorer-Model and then reconnect it.
I tried to delete the connection again, load the database and reconnect, but still, I get same results.
Why is this so? Any idea?

First, I make a database by clicking App_Data and add new Item. I add SQL Server Database. So that's why the entities has a .mdf extension.

Next, I add new tables on the database by right clicking the "Tables" and Add new Table on it. Insert new columns as well as the keys.

Then, I connect to the database by Right clicking Model in the Solution Explorer and add ADO.Net Entity Model. I used the Database.mdf for my connection. After that, it automatically generates the connection string in the web.config as well as the diagram.

Usually, when I made some changes in the database, I deleted the connection and reconnect again. Before I had no problems with it. The changes were seen upon reconnection but this time when I tried using with another app, I'm wondering why the modifications were not seen. I tried many times to connect and delete again the database but still nothing works.

Comment: Are you certain the changes exist in the database? Have you tried refreshing?

Comment: I tried refreshing it. The columns are all correct when I opened the database but when I load it in the Model, it doesn't have matching column names.

Comment: Can you please provide some code how do you connect to database and what operations do you perform?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you works directly with `.mdf` file. Consecuently, each time when you starts your application it copies into Debug folder and if you work with this local copy (it depends on your connection string in `App.config`) you change data exactly in Debug folder. So, each time you erase your changes when application starts, try to changes your connnection string.

Comment: I tried to delete the connection string and connect again the database. Still same situation occurs.

Comment: Which folder do you connect?

Comment: Ok, and what string is in your `App.config` ?

Comment: I believe it was in Web.Config. It goes like this:

    <add name="Billing_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Billing_db.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Great, now in debug check what path your program uses (when connection is opened), is it the same that you connect via `VS 2012`? As I  understand situation VS connected to the some path, whereas your application uses file in you Debug folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76871/discussion-between-vladimir-semashkin-and-user4656677).